# Adding fallback fonts to the @font-face definition

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, font-family

Is it possible to add a fallback font directly to the definition of the font-face?

Example:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  src: url('fonts/MyWebFont.eot');
  src: url('fonts/MyWebFont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
  url('fonts/MyWebFont.woff') format('woff');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And then using it as font-family value with automatic fallback, like so:

```
p {
  font-family: MyWebFont;
}
```

My goal is not to having to define the fallback fonts everywhere I define a new font-family. If not like above, can I somehow achieve this without JavaScript? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, you cannot specify any fallback fonts inside a [`@font-face`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face) rule, because such a rule defines a font face and assigns a name to it. Inside the rule, the `font-family` part can contain only one name, the name you choose to assign. It would be pointless list several names there, since only the first one can possibly matter (and, besides, in this context no name has any predefined meaning, e.g. Arial would not mean the Arial font but be just an arbitrary assigned name).

Fallback fonts can be specified only in normal `font-family` rules.

Consider organizing your style sheet so that the relevant `font-family` list appears only once, using a suitable list of selectors, like

```
p, blockquote, .foobar, .something {
   font-family: MyWebFont, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You can totally add fallback fonts to a `@font-face` rule!* You don't add them to the `font-family` descriptor (that's for giving your font family a name); you add them to the `src` descriptor, which accepts multiple values. If the browser can't find (or doesn't support) the first font, it will try loading the next one, and so on. You can have it look for fonts installed on the user's system using the `local()` function:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: bodytext;
  src: url(fonts/MyWebFont.woff) format("woff"),
       local(Arial),
       local(Helvetica);
}
```

Some people may argue that `url()` and `local()` weren't designed to be used this way. Typically, they're used to provide local and remote versions of the *same* font, with the web-font functioning as a fallback if the local font can't be found. Here's such an example from the [W3C specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-3/#src-desc):

> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: MyGentium;
>   src: local(Gentium),    /* use locally available Gentium */
>        url(Gentium.woff); /* otherwise, download it */
> }
> ```

But there's nothing to say you can't use it in place of a regular font stack. Check out this W3C example:

> Create an alias for local Japanese fonts on different platforms:
>
> ```
> @font-face {
>   font-family: jpgothic;
>   src: local(HiraKakuPro-W3), local(Meiryo), local(IPAPGothic);
> }
> ```

*There are some caveats though. Don't expect this to work exactly like the familiar `font-family` stack that you're used to. Firstly, there's no fallback for individual characters that may not be supported by your font. Secondly, you can't refer to generic font-families (like `sans-serif`, `system-ui`, etc). For those features, you're stuck with the classic font stack. But you can happily use both features, encapsulating all your named fonts in the `@font-face` rule, and adding the generic font as your last-resort fallback in the `font-family` declaration:

```
p {
  font-family: bodytext, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Best explanation with possible hackaround (which has caveats). Thanks, was wondering the same.

Comment: Awesome explanation. Very well-written and descriptive.

Answer (score 2):

CSS Variables is one solution to stay DRY

```
:root {
     --MainFont: "Gotham", "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
     --HeavyFont: "Gotham Black", "Franklin Gothic Medium", "Arial Narrow", Arial, sans-serif;
}

body {
     font-family: $MainFont;
}
h1 {
    font-family: $HeavyFont;
}
```

Comment: CSS variables are accessed by using var() function.